# googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. More details: Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-go-client

I am trying to send an email with Gmail API. But I get this error

> googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
> More details:
> Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission

I think it might bee related to config, I also followed google's quickstart for Go
here is the getClient func:

```
func getClient(config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    tokFile := "token.json"
    tok, err := tokenFromFile(tokFile)

    if err != nil {
            tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
            saveToken(tokFile, tok)
    }
    return config.Client(context.Background(), tok)
}
```

here is the code send:

```
case "pass":
    
    templateData := struct {
        VerPass string
        
    }{
        VerPass: cont1,
        
    }

    emailBody, err := parseTemplate("ver.html", templateData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Parse Err")
        return false, err
     }
     
    var message gmail.Message
 
    emailTo := "To: " + to + "\r\n"
    subject := "Subject: " + sub + "\n"
    mime := "MIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\n"
    msg := []byte(emailTo + subject + mime + "\n" + emailBody)
 
    message.Raw = base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(msg)
 
    // Send the message
    fmt.Println("OOOOOYYYYY")
    //here is the problem
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
}

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.MailGoogleComScope)

if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
}
    client := getClient(config)

srv, err := gmail.New(client)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Gmail client: %v", err)
}
//GmailService
    res, err := srv.Users.Messages.Send("me", &message).Do() // change me
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Res Err")
        fmt.Println(err)
       return false, err
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
```

I tried `for config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.MailGoogleComScope)`, I tried  using `GmailReadonlyScope` and `gmail.GmailSendScope`, but I got the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your showing script, `getClient()` of `client := getClient(config)` cannot be seen. But, when this function includes a file with the access token and refresh token, when you delete the file and authorize the scopes again, what result will you obtain? But, if my understanding of your whole script is not correct, I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your reply, I have modified the question to show getClient. I deleted token.json and reauthorized but the same problem

Comment: solved I called the func twice

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that the user who has authorized your application to access their data has not granted your application enough permissions in order to do what you are trying to do.

You apear to be using the [user.message.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) method.  If you check the documentation you will find that that method requires that the user be authorized with one of the following scopes.

[image]

If you did follow [Googles quick start for go](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) then you used `gmail.GmailReadonlyScope` as a scope which will only give you read only access.
However your code now apears to contain the `mail.MailGoogleComScope` scope which should work however i am guessing you neglected to reauthorize the application.  And didn't see the comment in the tutorial

> // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.

I suggest you deleted token.json and then the application will require that you authorize it again and your code should work with the elevated permissions.

Comment: Hi dalmTo what you said is true, I just called the function twice which wasn't giving me the chance to permit that's all.